# error installing "react export excel" - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

**install "npm i react-export-excel" in my reactjs project but it loads me with an error and I couldn't fix: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\project\node_modules\react -export-excel\node_modules\xlsx'", doesn't let me use this library in my project, and so I create another project and remount the library, I always get the same error.**

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the path "node_module/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/package.json" and add to the end of the file

```js
 "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false
      }
```